# Playing Raw Video data in ios

Tags: ios, core-video

I have an audio file and a video file containing raw audio and video data respectively. I have successfully played the audio file on ios using CoreAudio and AudioToolBox Frameworks. Now I want to play the video file. I have tried playing the Video File using AVPlayer of AVFoundation Framework, but no luck, it gives the following error:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AVFoundationErrorDomain error -11800.)" UserInfo=0x5e6b990 {}

So can anyone please help me out. Are there some frameworks in ios for allocating buffer for the video data and rendering the data in a callback etc.

Thanks,